# Should I invalidate JWT when user deletes account?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt

I know its maybe a bit a broad question and as I can see from reading, invalidating jwt on logout is usually not done as the only way would be to save a blacklist of tokens into the db and then always check against it which is against the stateless anture of jwt.
I do wonder however, if this is common practice also when a user deletes the account for security reasons?
Thanks!